# rails5 `filter_parameters` doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following in my `config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb`

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Configure sensitive parameters which will be filtered from the log file.
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [:password, :reset_password_token, :confirmation_token, :unlock_token, :two_step_auth_token]
```

But when I execute and update for `two_step_auth_token` column the log is not filtered, even though I restarted the server:

```
UPDATE `users` SET `two_step_auth_token` = 'tb0437', `two_step_auth_token_sent_at` = '2017-04-29 20:12:49', `two_step_auth_token_confirmed_at` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2017-04-29 20:12:49' WHERE `users`.`id` = 1
```

What is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter out sensitive **request parameters** from your log files, not a sql queries.

<sub>[ref](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#log-filtering)</sub>

Comment: Oops! So how can I filter out sql queries from log too?

Comment: `config.log_level = :info` in `config/environments/development.rb`